# No he podido hacer mi botón de guardar funcionar

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

He tenido un problema persistente respecto al botón guardar.

Mis códigos

```
<?php

class SaveController extends CI_Controller
{
    public function process()
    {
        $first = $this->input->post("cuenta");
        $password = $this->input->post("password");

        if ($this->loginmodel->saveData($first, $password))
        {
            $data["Cuentas"] = $this->accountmodel->getAllAccountInfo();
            $this->load->view('admin/index', $data);
    }
}

<?php

class AccountModel extends CI_Model 
{
    public function getAllAccountInfo()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT cuenta, nombre, buscar, pago, monto, fecha, banco, interes, concepto, cuota, credito, debito FROM accounts');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    public function savedata()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('INSERT INTO 'accounts' (cuenta, nombre, buscar, pago, monto, fecha, banco, interes, concepto, cuota, credito, debito'));
        return $query->result_array();

        $this->db->where('cuenta', $user);
        $this->db->where('password', $pass);
        $query = $this->db->get('accounts');
        if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

// Formulario HTML

```
div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">Cuenta</label>  
<div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
<input  name="first" placeholder="Número de Cuenta" class="form-control"  type="text">
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Nombres</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input  name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<!-- Text input-->
       <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Fecha</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
  <input name="email" placeholder="Fecha" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Banco</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i></span>
  <input name="phone" placeholder="Banco" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Monto</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i></span>
  <input name="address" placeholder="Monto" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Cuota</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
  <input name="city" placeholder="Cuota" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->

<div class="form-group"> 
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Pago</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
    <select name="Pago" class="form-control selectpicker" >
      <option value=" " >Seleccionar Tipo de Pago</option>
      <option>Efectivo</option>
      <option>Tarjeta de Crédito</option>
      <option >Tarjeta de Débito</option>
      <option >Cheque</option>

    </select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Interés</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i></span>
  <input name="zip" placeholder="Interés" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<!-- radio checks -->

<!-- Text area -->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Comentario</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Comentario"></textarea>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Success message -->
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Success <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" >Guardar<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->
  <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-reverse">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cuenta</td>
                    <td>Nombres</td>
          <td>Monto</td>
          <td>Fecha</td>
                    <td>Pago</td>
                    <td>Banco</td>
          <td>Cuota</td>
          <td>Interés</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($Cuentas as $c): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $c['cuenta'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $c['nombre'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $c['monto'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $c['fecha'];?></td>
             <td><?php echo $c['pago'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $c['banco'];?></td>
               <td><?php echo $c['cuota'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $c['interes'];?></td>              
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Oye una duda.. en tu Model si tienes el método: saveData ?, porque en el Modelo: AccountModel tienes un método: saveData.. Ahora quiero suponer que los modelos previamente ya los cargaste???...

Comment: SaveData lo tengo incluido con el AccountModel

Comment: @JoséQuezada, no te recomiendo compartir información así en sitios web, (así sea un sitio "de prueba").

Comment: @JoséQuezada oye entre a tu sistema y observo algo muy pelicular, cuando envias el submit solo estas enviando las siguiente variables: first,
nombre, email, phone, address, city, Pago, zip, comment. Pero en tu Controller; `SaveController` tu estas solicitando recuperar las variables: cuenta, password.

Comment: Sí, respecto a eso es que sólo estoy intentado enviar un sólo campo a ver si guarda..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basandonos en que el el `saveData`se localiza en el model `AccountModel` entonces debes cambiar el siguiente if:

```
if ($this->loginmodel->saveData($first, $password))
```

por lo siguiente:

```
if ($this->accountmodel->saveData($first, $password))
```

porque el método de saveData se encuentra en `AccountModel`

---

**ACTUALIZACION**

Actualiza tu Controlador

```
class SaveController extends CI_Controller
{
    public function process()
    {
        //echo "entre al metodo process<br/>";
        $cuenta = $this->input->post("first");
        $nombres = $this->input->post("nombre");
        $fecha = $this->input->post("fecha");
        $banco = $this->input->post("banco");
        $monto = $this->input->post("monto");
        $cuota = $this->input->post("cuota");
        $pago = $this->input->post("pago");
        $interes = $this->input->post("interes");

        $data['c_'] = $cuenta ? $cuenta : null; 
        $data['n_'] = $nombres ? $nombres : null;
        $data['f_'] = $fecha ? $fecha : null;
        $data['b_'] = $banco ? $banco : null;
        $data['m_'] = $monto ? $monto : null;
        $data['cu_'] = $cuota ? $cuota : null;
        $data['p_'] = $pago ? $pago : null;
        $data['i_'] = $interes ? $interes : null;

        $this->AccountModel->saveData($data);
    }

}
```

Ahora vamos actualizando tu modelo

```
class AccountModel extends CI_Model 
{
    public function getAllAccountInfo()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT cuenta, nombre, buscar, pago, monto, fecha, banco, interes, concepto, cuota, credito, debito FROM accounts');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    public function saveData($data)
    {
        $datos = array('cuenta'=>$data['c_'],'nombre'=>$data['n_'],'fecha'=>$data['f_'],
            'banco'=>$data['b_'],'monto'=>$data['m_'],'cuota'=>$data['cu_'],'pago'=>$data['p_'],'interes'=>$data['i_']);

        $this->db->insert('accounts',$datos);
    }
}
```

Comment: ya he ssacado la función de ahí adentro, he creado una modelo llamado savedata y ahora me da error 500

`<?php

 class SaveController extends CI_Controller
 {
  public function process()
  {
   $this->load->model('savedatamodel');
   $first = $this->input->post("cuenta");
   $password = $this->input->post("password");

   if ($this->savedatamodel->savedata($first, $password))
      {
    $data["Cuentas"] = $this->accountmodel->getAllAccountInfo();
    $this->load->view('admin/index', $data);
  }
 }
?>`

Comment: `<?php

 Class savedata extends CI_model
 {
public function savedatamodel()
        {
            $query = $this->db->query('INSERT INTO 'accounts' (cuenta, nombre, buscar, pago, monto, fecha, banco, interes, concepto, cuota, credito, debito'));
            return $query->result_array();

            
                return true;
            return false;
        }
       }
        ?>`

Comment: es que no necesitas sacar la función de esa clase, puede estar ahi sin problemas... solo que yo creo que no estas enviando la información correcta a donde debe ser... Porque no creamos una sala de chat para poder extendernos mas sobre el problema y cuando encontremos la solución la posteamos aquí.

Comment: Claro, como usted desee.

Comment: haber accesa al siguiente chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43471/pregunta-19632-boton-que-no-guarda-codeigniter

Comment: Hey hermano, tengo tiempo dentro ya, te pedí request hace unos 20 min!

Comment: estoy en el chat... ahi te espero...

Comment: Amigo, disculpa me ignorancia. Pero como hago para escribir? Haha

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43480/discussion-between-alfonso-carrasco-and-jose-quezada).

Comment: Alfonso Carrasco, necesito tu ayuda como te contacto?

Comment: En mi perfil puedes encontrar detalles para contacto...